# What happens when Animal Companions and Familiars hit 0 hp or less?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars, animal-companions, hit-points

When a Druid's animal companion's hit points drops to 0 (or lower), does it die? Or does it becomes disabled (unconscious) and can it be healed by the party cleric?
What about Wizard familiars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### All living creatures:

Die at −10 HP, and are [Dying](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#dying) from −1 to −9 HP. They can be brought back to life with spells like *raise dead*. Animal companions and familiars don’t have any particular special rules for this.

Constructs and the undead are just destroyed when they hit 0 HP. They, and Outsiders and Elementals, are much harder to bring back to life.

#### Animal Companions

Can be replaced relatively easily:

> If a druid releases her companion from service, she may gain a new one by performing a ceremony requiring 24 uninterrupted hours of prayer. **This ceremony can also replace an animal companion that has perished.**

#### Familiars

Not so easily replaced; the ceremony to get one costs 100 gp, and more importantly,

> If the familiar dies or is dismissed by the sorcerer, the sorcerer [or wizard] must attempt a DC 15 Fortitude saving throw. Failure means **he loses 200 experience points per sorcerer level;** success reduces the loss to one-half that amount. [...] **A slain or dismissed familiar cannot be replaced for a year and day.**

Note that this XP loss happens even if you bring the familiar back to life with e.g. *raise dead*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! One more stupid question: If enemies (NPC ruled by DM) are living creatures and have healing spells than in combat they first fall to dying with possibility to be bringed back to life? I dont mean parties like 4 Goblins.
And can be animal companion healed by Cleric or only by Druid itself?

Comment: @ZiCold If they are dying but not dead (between −1 and −9 HP), yes, they can be healed. Once dead, they have to use more powerful magic like *raise dead*, which isn't likely to happen in combat. Healing spells work on anything alive, so the cleric can heal the druid's animal companion. The druid might get some special animal companion-only healing spells; I don't remember.

Comment: Thans for your answer again!